# Auto map JSON AJAX returned data to table row in Jquery/JavaScript

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, json, ajax

Ok I have created a tab with a table inside of it as follows -

```
function createTab(Name, id) {
    var $button = $('<button/>', {
        'class': 'tablinks',
        'onclick': 'return false;',
        'id': name,
        text: Name,
        click: function () {
            return false;
        }
    });
    var $div = $('<div>').prop({
        id: Name,
        'name': id + 'MKTTAB',
        className: 'tabcontent'
    })
    var $table = $('<table cellspacing="0" rules="all" class="RFPGRID" style="border-color:Black;border-width:1px;border-style:Solid;border-collapse:collapse;">');
    $table.append('<caption>' + Name + '</caption>')
    var $tbody = $table.append('<tbody />').children('tbody');
    $tbody.append('<tr />').children('tr:last');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST", url: "../WebMethods/MarketPersuitMethods.aspx/GetColumnHeaders",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function (res) {

            $.each(res.d, function (data, value) {
                $tbody.append("<th>" + value.ColumnsName + "</th>");

            });
            $tbody.append('<tr />').children('tr:last')
            setTimeout(function () {
            }, 1000);
        }
    });
   
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../WebMethods/MarketPersuitMethods.aspx/GetQueryInfo",
        data: {},
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
          //HERE IS MY ISSUES
             $tbody.append("<td>" + value.ColumnsName + "</td>");
        }
    });
    //$table.appendTo('#TabbedMktList');
    $button.appendTo('#tabs');
    $table.appendTo($div);
    $div.appendTo('#TabbedMktList');
}
```

Here is my C# Code

```
    [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    public static string GetQueryInfo()
    {
        String daresult = null;
        DataTable yourDatable = new DataTable();


        string strConnString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TimeClock"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        cmd.CommandText = "select  *  from OCI_TEXT_PROJECT_MASTER where proj_id=2049";
        da.SelectCommand = cmd;
        cmd.CommandTimeout = 30;
        cmd.Connection = con;
        con.Open();
        da.Fill(yourDatable);


      
        daresult = DataSetToJSON(yourDatable);
        return daresult;
    }

    public static string DataSetToJSON(DataTable table)
    {
        string JSONString = string.Empty;
        JSONString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(table);
        return JSONString;
    }
```

It is creating the column headers as I wish for it to do. However, I need to populate all the JSON data for the rows below it. I would not know the column headers as they can change.

I am able to see my results are coming back in JSON data -

```
[{"Project ID":"18180","OPRN":null,"Proj_Type":"2049","Client Name":null,"client_id":null,"ClientContact":null,"Contact_ID":null,"PN":null,"CompleteDate":"2020-05-21T00:00:00","cost":null,"SQFT":2000,"BIM":null,"LEED":"NO        ","Delivery_Meth":"Corey ","City":"Orlando","State":"FL        ","County":"Orange","IT":"1141","Project Name":null,"Address":"1234. Orlando Ave","zip":"12345","notes":"<p class=\"MsoNormal\"><b>EXTRA TESTING 1-2-3-43</b></p>","PM":"1141","OLDOWNER":null,"Owner_Contact":null,"ProjectManager":"Corey ","Architect":"Collier Health Services","ContractorORG":"BVW Development","ArchitectID":929,"PNAME":"OCI DYNAMICS CRM PROJECT MANAGEMENT SOFTWARE","PROJ_ID":2049,"Office":"Maitland","MPROJECT":null,"Contractor":930,"addr2":"","PROJSTATUS":2,"TotalProjectTime":null,"corp":"0","ProjectStatus":"Construction","TotalDesignTime":null,"OFFNUM":1,"Owner":null,"ProjectType":null,"MarketSector":"FINANCIAL","users":"1141","team":null,"BuildingType":null,"ETA":null,"designstartdate":null,"FINALCONTRUCT":24000.0000,"ESTCONSTRUCT":15000.0000,"Units":"12","WebType":"P","RequestedBy":null,"RequestedDate":null,"Status":"Interview","RFPDATE":null,"SENTDATE":null,"InterviewDate":null,"OCIDATE":null,"Method":null,"ContractType":"0","ContractName":null,"Tags":"CRM FINANCIAL NewTest rigtest2","TotalProfit/Loss":3,"Disciplines":"Mechanical, CAD, Clerical, QA/QC, Project Management","ChillerType":"1","Revit":"2017","Tons":145,"Rooms":5}]
```

However -

I have no idea where to get it to map over automatically.

I would ideally think somehow to map it based on the TH header text because they would be the same.

My issue is somewhere in here

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../WebMethods/MarketPersuitMethods.aspx/GetQueryInfo",
        data: {},
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
          //HERE IS MY ISSUES
             $tbody.append("<td>" + value.ColumnsName + "</td>");
        }
    });
```

Comment: try JSON.parse(data); This would deserialize you string data into JSON.

Comment: You have `success: function (data)` and you are trying to access it by `value`: `$tbody.append("<td>" + value.ColumnsName + "</td>");`. You need to change your `success` function to: `success: function (data, value)`

Comment: well i do not know the column names perhaps looking for an iteration statement to add all the rows that it finds.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out -

```
function createTab(Name, id) {
    var $button = $('<button/>', {
        'class': 'tablinks',
        'onclick': 'return false;',
        'id': name,
        text: Name,
        click: function () {
            return false;
        }
    });
    var $div = $('<div>').prop({
        id: Name,
        'name': id + 'MKTTAB',
        className: 'tabcontent'
    })
    var $table = $('<table cellspacing="0" rules="all" class="RFPGRID" style="border-color:Black;border-width:1px;border-style:Solid;border-collapse:collapse;">');
    $table.append('<caption>' + Name + '</caption>')
    var $tbody = $table.append('<tbody />').children('tbody');
    $tbody.append('<tr />').children('tr:last');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../WebMethods/MarketPersuitMethods.aspx/GetQueryInfo",
        data: {},
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (d) {
            var data = $.parseJSON(d.d);
            var colHeader = Object.keys(data[0]);
            for (var i = 0; i < colHeader.length; i++) {
                $tbody.append("<th>" + colHeader[i] + "</th>");
            }
            //sets new line
            $tbody.append('<tr />').children('tr:last')
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

                for (var j = 0; j < colHeader.length; j++) {

                    $tbody.append('<td>' + data[i][colHeader[j]] + '</td>');
                }
                $tbody.append('<tr />').children('tr:last')
            }

            setTimeout(function () {
            }, 1000);
        }

    });
    $button.appendTo('#tabs');
    $table.appendTo($div);
    $div.appendTo('#TabbedMktList');
}
```